# Is there a continuous injective map from $\mathbb{R}$ that has compact image?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose I have a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to X$, where $X$ is some non-compact metric space.

Is it possible that $f$ is injective yet has compact image? If the answer is yes, what characterizes those cases? What additional properties would make the answer negative?

My progress so far: If the image is compact, $f(n)$ has a convergent subsequence with limit in the image, i.e. $f(a_n) \to f(a)$ where $a_n \to \infty$. But I find it tricky to turn the limit into equality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $f$ an immersion of $\mathbb{R}$ which makes a figure eight:

[image]

Comment: Huh, that's pretty much the same as what I thought, only much simpler...

Comment: Ah, okay, with the image, I see it more clearly

Comment: Then again, mine can be done without diminishing derivative, so I guess it still says something. :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. Consider a function $f\colon {\bf R}\to {\bf R}^2$ which takes the line to a doubled topologist's sine curve, looping around through the central interval.

This map can be made to be differentiable, and an arc length parametrisation, so requiring this property won't make the answer negative (not even in addition to requiring $X$ to be euclidean).