# No bijective continuous function from upper half plane to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

If we take $H := \{z \in \mathbb{C}\ : im(z) \geq 0\}$. Is there a continuous bijective function from $H$ to $\mathbb{C}$?

$H$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$, because we include the real line in $H$. So there can't be a bijective continuous map with an inverse that is also continuous. But I can't seem to find a map $H \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ that would be continuous and bijective at all.

I'm wondering if it's the same situation as in the real numbers, where two connected $X,Y \subset \mathbb{R}$ are already homeomorphic if there's a continuous bijection from $X \longrightarrow Y$, and there's no necessity to check that the inverse is continuous.

But to go back to the example with $H$ and $\mathbb{C}$. It could be that they're not isomorphic, but that there is a continuous bijection from $H$ to $\mathbb{C}$, but the inverse wouldn't be continuous. So that's why I'm wondering if there is a continuous bijection from $H$ to $\mathbb{C}$ at all.

Comment: I think this was asked few years ago and the answer was negative. The reason was that every closed subset of the plane which is the image of a continuous bijection from a line, has to separate the plane.

Comment: Just to be clear, by "answer is negative" you mean that there is no bijective continuous function $H \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$, right?

Comment: This is right................

Comment: Your statement about subsets of $\mathbb {R}$ is wrong. For example, let $X = [0,1) \cup \{2\}$, $Y=[0,1]$ and let $f$ be the identity on $[0,1)$, $f(2) = 1$.

Comment: I should have been more specific, what I meant were connected subsets $X$ and $Y$. Would that change anything?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}$ is open but $H$ is not open.

Comment: @Ris, $H$ is open in $H$.

Comment: Any thoughts about the answer?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, indeed, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362845/is-the-complement-of-an-injective-continuous-map-mathbbr-to-mathbbr2-wi) closely related question was asked and answered earlier.

**Theorem.** There is no continuous bijection $H\to {\mathbb C}$.

**Proof.** Suppose that there exists $f: H\to {\mathbb C}$, a continuous bijection. The restriction of $f$ to the open half-plane 
$$
U= \{z: Im(z)>0\}
$$
is still a continuous injective map. Hence, by the [invariance of domain theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain), $f(U)$ is open in ${\mathbb C}$. Since $f(H)={\mathbb C}$, the image $f(L)$ is closed in ${\mathbb C}$, where $L$ is the boundary line of $H$, i.e. the real line in the complex plane.

Now, we have a continuous injective map $f: L\to f(L)\subset {\mathbb C}$ with closed image. By my answer to the linked question, $f(L)$ separates ${\mathbb C}$ into at least two components. But ${\mathbb C}- f(L)=f(U)$ is connected. A contradiction. qed